# Print SOAP request results to a XML file on my server

Tags: xml, soap

I'm quite new to SOAP and I need some help. I've written a script that calls an action in the SOAP feed and I get a valid response in the browser. What I don't know is how to get that response to be saved in an XML file directly on my server.
This is the code I use:

```
<?php 
class Login 
{public $Username; 
public $Password; 
public function __construct($Username, $Password) 
{$this->Username = $Username; 
 $this->Password = $Password; 
} 
} 
$Username = ""; 
$Password = ""; 
$url = ""; 
$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0)); 
$result = $client->__soapCall("GetCatalog", array("GetCatalog" => array ("Username" =>$Username, "Password" =>$Password)));
echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>"; 
?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [__getLastResponse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php).

An example from that page:

```
<?php
$client = SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$result = $client->SomeFunction();
echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
?>
```